# Wait when data is fetch react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, formik

I have problem with the useState dataTemp. This variable dataTemp is undefined. How Can I wait that this variable will be fill from the function getTemp?

```
useEffect(() => {
let prod = prod.find(
  (prod) =>
    prod.name.toString() === searchParams.get("name")
);
if (prod !== undefined) {
  formik.setFieldValue("prod", {
    label: prod.name
     id: prod.id
  });

  getTemp(prod.id)
    .then((response) => {
      setDataTemp(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {});
}

let temp = dataTemp.find(
  (temp) => temp.name.toString() === searchParams.get("temp2")
);
console.log(temp);
```

}, [searchParams]);

Comment: i see dataTemp is never declared or used

Comment: it's decleared as useState [dataTemp, setDataTemp] = useState([]);

Comment: i thing your are calling the variable before set value considerated async call

Comment: async to getTemp ?

Comment: yes, i undertand youre are use setDataTemp method to bind this variable and use on let temp = dataTemp.find for use it, that i said that is have to call variable after set value to variable

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Could tell me how is this can be write. beacuse not change :(

Comment: what is the code of setDataTemp method?

Comment: That's all code of setDataTemp